# Simple multi-threading - combining statements to two lines

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

If I have:

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { MessageBox.Show("Test"); };
new Thread(starter).Start();
```

How can I combine this into one line of code?  I've tried:

```
new Thread(delegate { MessageBox.Show("Test"); }).Start();
```

But I get this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the
>   following methods or properties:
>   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)'
>   and
>   'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)'

Answer (score 9):

```
new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show("Test")).Start();
```

or

```
new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { MessageBox.Show("Test"); }).Start();
```

or

```
new Thread(delegate() { MessageBox.Show("Test"); }).Start();
```

The problem is when you declared a delegate without specifying how many parameters it had, the compiler didn't know whether you meant ThreadStart(0 parameters) or ParameterizedThreadStart(1 parameter).